# Eclipse error(s)_during_the_evaluation for watch expression having quotes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In the Eclipse Debug perspective, when using quotes in the watch expression it returns the error `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`

like for example:

```
 Log.i("A","blah")
```

will return `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`

or

```
solo.getWebElement(By.className("title"), 0)
```

will return `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`

This works fine during the code execution. Any other expression not having any quotes in it will work fine. I tried to escape with "\" or "", but no luck (It's Java/Android code by the way).

Any idea how I could use these expressions in the Java debugger Watch Expression?

Comment: The problem might be more in the fact that you seem to be calling static variables than in the quotes...

Comment: you are right!!!
I just tried

 solo.getWebElement(com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.By.className("title"), 0);

or

 android.util.Log.i("A","blah");  

and it works!

Comment: i make it an answer for sake of history.

Comment: I get this problem even with an expression as simple as "1+2". Anyone any ideas? This is on Eclipse Helios debuggging a Java 6 JRE.

Comment: @hktegner - did you find the answer to your question ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 - Sorry, it's such a long time ago that I can't remember and I don't use Helios anymore. It probably turned out to be some kind of environment problem (java version in IDE vs version in running process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be more in the fact that you seem to be calling static variables than in the quotes. You should declare the whole classname including package to make it works.